# Orocommerce - Authenticated GET requests to products and categories fail

Tags: orocommerce

I am encountering a 500 error when issuing an authenticated GET request to `/api/products` and `/api/categories`, via Postman and curl. The API request is:

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://HOST-IP/api/products?page[number]=1&page[size]=10&sort=id' \
  -H 'Accept: application/vnd.api+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXX' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json'
```

From the prod.log, the output for `/api/products` is:

```
api.ERROR: The execution of "oro_api.load_entities_by_entity_serializer" processor is failed. 
{"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Call to a member function getId() on null 
at /var/www/html/commerce/vendor/oro/commerce/src/Oro/Bundle/RedirectBundle/Api/Processor/ComputeUrlFields.php:83)",
"action":"get_list","requestType":"rest,json_api,frontend","version":"latest","class":"Oro\\Bundle\\ProductBundle\\Entity\\Product"} []
```

Checking line 83 of `ComputeUrlFields.php`, references the `LocalizationHelper`, which exists at:`/var/www/html/commerce/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/LocaleBundle/Helper`

These APIs work successfully via the Sandbox. Also, I am able to make other authenticated API requests, such as GET `/api/productimages` and `/api/productfamilies`. Any thoughts on the failure? I have not changed any bundles, from the AWS Marketplace image.

Orocommerce Version: 4.2.1

Current Localization settings:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your environment or administration setup.

We tried to reproduce an issue on a clean AWS instance with no luck.
Also, pay attention, that there is no "/api/categories" resource, but there is "/api/mastercatalogcategories" that works with no issues with your steps to reproduce, same as "/api/products".

According to the stack trace, something is wrong with the localization detection or default localization configuration. See https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/configuration/system/general-setup/global-localization/.

I could recommend using xDebug to find the root cause, or, as a workaround, you can set the localization explicitly using the `X-Localization-ID` header.

Comment: Andrey, I have attached a screen capture of the localizations settings above. This is out-of-the-box on the AWS image. Not edits have been performed. What config file stores the settings on the back-end, so that I may verify they are set correctly?

Secondly, what's the proper format for the value of the `X-Localization-ID` header? en, en-US, US, etc

Comment: > What config file stores the settings on the back-end, so that I may verify they are set correctly? it is stored in the database. If the value is rendered correctly in UI, then it's the same in the database. So the issue is in something else.

Comment: You can fetch the list of available localizations with their ids using `GET /api/localizations
` resource.